# Nullable restrictions

Tags: c#

Does anyone know why this code doesn't compile?

```
Nullable<Nullable<int>> n = null;
```

I realize Nullable has a constraint

```
where T : struct
```

But Nullable is struct. I also know this constraint has a restriction "The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).
So how does it work? Is this solved on compiler level?

Comment: What would be the point of a nested nullable?

Comment: Nullable [Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs) for reference.  I'm not actually seeing where the restriction comes from. `T` is restricted to `struct`, and `Nullable<T>` is defined as a `struct`, so logically, it should work. Not that I can't think of any sane reason to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is:

> The type `int?` must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it
>   as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `Nullable<T>`

So it must not only be a value type but a *non-nullable* value type. But `Nullable<int>` is a nullable value type.

Here's the [compiler error CS0453](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0453) which also shows this example:

> This error occurs when you use a non-value type argument in
>   instantiating a generic type or method which has the value constraint
>   on it. **It can also occur when you use a nullable value type argument**.

Q: Is this solved on compiler level?

Yes, which means it' not very interesting to know how they achieved this constraint. It's an implementation detail of the compiler which doesn't need to use a C# language feature.

---

> Why is not allowed?

Well, what would be the benefit of a `Nullable<Nulable<int>>`? Nullables were introduced to give value types the opportunity to be `null`(so undefined, without value). This is already achieved for a `Nullable<int>`, it can be `null`. So by nesting it in another nullable you would not get anything. It's not allowed for the same reason why you can't have a `Nullable<string>`, a string as every other reference type can already be `null`.

Comment: Any idea on how this behaviour is actually archieved? I'm not aware of any constraint for non-nullable types (or I don't know them yet)

Comment: The compiler can impose more constraints than you can put after a `where` ...

Comment: @CShark: ask Erip Lippert, i haven't helped to create the compiler. But of course a compiler has more options than a C# developer using the .NET framework.